# SQL Order By not working as I would like it to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some woes with the Order By in my SQL.

I would like to have my results (see below) from the following sql to order by the following columns in desc order, but applying the order by at the end of the whole sql only orders by the first column and ignores the rest.

The columns are; FinPen, CWPPen, GAPPen, EGPen, WarPen and IPD. But if you look at the results they are only ordered by FinPen.

How can I alter my sql to get the required results?

SQL code:

```
WITH tbl_All AS
(
  SELECT dealername,
         (CASE WHEN backsell = 0 AND isnonopportunity = 0 AND financeopportunity = 1 THEN units END) AS units,
         (CASE WHEN backsell = 0 AND isnonopportunity = 0 AND financeopportunity = 1 AND financetype IS NOT NULL THEN units END) AS numadvance,
         (CASE WHEN cwpcommission <> 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS totalppi,
         (CASE WHEN gapsell <> 0 THEN 1.0 END) AS totalgap,
         (CASE WHEN supagardsell <> 0 THEN 1.0 END) AS totalsuper,
         (CASE WHEN warrantysell <> 0 AND financeopportunity = 1 AND delivered = 1 THEN 1.0 END) AS totalwar,
         (financecommission + warrantycommission + gapcommission + cwpcommission + supagardcommission + volumebonus - subsidy) AS totalipd
  FROM tbl_synergy_controllogs
  WHERE period >= '01/01/2018'
    AND period <= '10/01/2018'
    AND dealername NOT LIKE '%comm%'
    AND newcar = '1'
), tbl_SUM AS
(
  SELECT dealername AS udm,
         sum(units) AS units,
         dealername AS fdm,
         cast(count(numadvance) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS numadvance,
         dealername AS cdm,
         cast(count(totalppi) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS totppi,
         dealername AS gdm,
         cast(count(totalgap) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS totgap,
         dealername AS edm,
         cast(count(totalsuper) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS totsup,
         dealername AS wdm,
         cast(count(totalwar) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS totwar,
         dealername AS idm,
         sum(totalipd) AS totalipd
  FROM tbl_all
  GROUP BY dealername
), tbl_CALC AS
(
  SELECT udm,
         units,
         fdm,
         numadvance / units AS finpen,
         cdm,
         totppi / units AS cwppen,
         gdm,
         totgap / units AS gappen,
         edm,
         totsup / units AS egpen,
         wdm,
         totwar / units AS warpen,
         idm,
         totalipd / units AS ipd
  FROM tbl_sum
)
SELECT *
FROM tbl_calc
ORDER BY finpen DESC, cwppen DESC, gappen DESC, egpen DESC, warpen DESC, ipd DESC
```

Results:

```
UDM      | Units | FDM      | FinPen            | CDM           |CWPPen         |GDM        |GAPPen         |EDM        |EGPen          |WDM        |WarPen         |IDM        |IPD
which co | 237   | which co | 0.928270042       | which co      |1.008438819    |which co   |0.827004219    |which co   |0.405063291    |which co   |0.004219409    |which co   |569.924303
that co  | 117   | that co  | 0.914529915       | that co       |1.034188034    |that co    |0.743589744    |that co    |0.367521368    |that co    |0.094017094    |that co    |544.309743
what co  | 208   | what co  | 0.908653846       | what co       |1.028846154    |what co    |0.783653846    |what co    |0.557692308    |what co    |0.009615385    |what co    |622.47375
zzz co   | 161   | zzz co   | 0.906832298       | zzz co        |1.01863354     |zzz co     |0.639751553    |zzz co     |0.49068323     |zzz co     |0.130434783    |zzz co     |433.015714
def co   | 177   | def co   | 0.892655367       | def co        |1.04519774     |def co     |0.570621469    |def co     |0.463276836    |def co     |0              |def co     |387.078305
abc co   | 211   | abc co   | 0.890995261       | abc co        |1.08056872     |abc co     |0.663507109    |abc co     |0.777251185    |abc co     |0              |abc co     |466.44
```

Please can someone help me out, preferably with some code sample/example?

Thanks

PS. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Your result is ordered by FinPen descending. Which result do you want?

Comment: Your result is CORRECT !
Put more data, so you can see the other applied orders DESC.

Comment: You have 6 order by columns, you should have at least 6*6 = 36 rows, and maybe you can see something with real ordering.

Comment: If you would have records with the same value for FinPen, you would see that the next ordering criterium (CWPPen desc) will be used to order those rows.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: ORDER BY sorts rows. First when there are FinPen duplicates, the ORDER BY considers cwppen values, etc-

Comment: Perhaps you could round them down or reduce the noise (like placing all <0.5 values in one group, <1.0 in another).

Comment: @jarlh  Is there a way to order columns independently, i.e. order col1 then order col2...so each column has the highest to lowest?  Thanks

Comment: No, row for row is how SQL works.